# PHP not displaying text colour

Tags: php

I have a page which I would like to see display the team played for in green. I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT performance.id, matchid, playerid, team, debut, batpos, runs, ballsfaced, runs/ballsfaced*100 AS strikerate, fours, sixes, no, howout, fielder, bowler, ballsbowled, maidens, wickets, runsconceded, catches, stumpings, runouts, runsconceded/ballsbowled/6 AS economy, matches.round, matches.season, teams.id AS fteamid, a.id AS ateamid, teams.name AS hometeamname, a.name AS awayteamname, players.fname, players.surname 
                    FROM performance 
                    INNER JOIN matches ON performance.matchid=matches.id 
                    INNER JOIN teams ON matches.hometeam = teams.id 
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT teams.id, name FROM teams) AS a ON matches.awayteam = a.id
                    INNER JOIN players ON performance.playerid=players.id
```

And the following php statement:

```
<?php 
          //if they play for this team display in green
          if ($team['team'] == $team['fteamid']){
          ?>
          <font color="green"><?php htmlout($team['hometeamname']); ?></font>
          <?php } else {
              ?> <?php htmlout($team['hometeamname']); ?> 
              <?php } ?>
              v 
              <?php 
          //if they play for this team display in green
          if ($team['team'] == $team['ateamid']){
          ?>
          <font color="green"><?php htmlout($team['awayteamname']); ?></font>
          <?php } else {
              ?> <?php htmlout($team['awayteamname']); ?> 
              <?php } ?>
```

It works fine for the home team, but it doesn't work for the away team and I can't figure out why, it appears to be correct to me. Can someone please point out my error?

Comment: Please use css instat of font tags.

Comment: is your resulting rowset contain row with $team['team'] == $team['ateamid']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was an error with the table, not the code

Answer (score -1):

Well if I see it right you forgot to set a color in your else case.

```
if ($team['team'] == $team['fteamid']){
    $color="green";
} else {
    $color="red";
}
$html= htmlout($team['awayteamname']); 
echo "<span color='color:$color'>$html</span>";
```

Comment: No I didn't, I want it black how it is if you don't set a colour, it's the away team one which doesn't work, home team works perfectly